What building is burning before the coronation in House of the Dragon?
In House of the Dragon S1E9 "The Green Council," as citizens are being "ushered" to the coronation, there is a wide shot that indicates a building is burning.

What building is burning?
In discussion with my wife, we feel it is one of three possibilities:

The fighting pits where young children were being forced to fight (Otto's deal with the White Worm)
The brothel of the White Worm
A building used to house the spies captured by Lord Larys (Ser Foot).

Any ideas?

https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/118866/what-is-the-burning-building-this-character-walks-past-in-the-city

Per the official audio description,

"He takes her by the arm and guides her down the stairs. Pre-dawn light glows softly in the sky.
Flames engulf Mysaria's house.
A figure in a dark cloak strides away from the burning building, their face hidden by their hood. The grey flames twist out of the window and blackening smoke plumes from it."


I find the closed caption audio description on Netflix very useful for trying to understand what the heck is going on on shows like these.

This was later confirmed that it was indeed Mysaria's house that burned.  In the show, S2E2 "Rhaenyra the Cruel" by Mysaria herself in a discussion with Rhaenys on why she would never betray her.
IMHO, it was a bit out of character for Otto (who was suspected of ordering the burning) given his cool and calculated nature.  Mysaria did nothing to harm the crown or his family, only acted in her best interest and that of all of flea bottom.  (She asked for the childhood fighting pit to be put out of business.)
She could have been a good ally for the green's and has already proven herself at a great ally to Rhaenys.

How was it confirmed?

Also, confirmed as what?
